# Can't input new order

Tags: c

Okay, hopefully after this, I won't ask anymore questions here. I redid the entire code, replacing gets() with scanf(). Now though, whenever I choose to put a new order for the program, I just put the name and the process just ends, showing "return value 3221225477", preventing me from typing in the address, request and price. I screwed up somewhere, but I don't know what. Here's what I did:

Translation:

- Case 1: Type name, address, order, total price.
- Case 2: Search for code (Issue: new string overwrites old one  constantly)
- Case 3: Show list of all orders created.
- Case 4: Exit

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TAM 100

struct order
{
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[150];
    char pedido[300];
    char valor[10];
};

int main() 
{
    struct order lista[TAM];
    int busca, acha, i, menu;
    menu = 0;
    int codigo = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while(menu != 4)
    {
        system("cls");

        printf("====================\n");
        printf("Selecione uma opcao\n");
        printf("====================\n");
        printf("1 - Cadastrar pedido\n");
        printf("2 - Consultar pedido\n");
        printf("3 - Emitir relatorio\n");
        printf("4 - Sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");

                printf("Digite seu nome: \n");
                scanf("%49[^\n]", lista[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("Digite seu endereco: \n");
                scanf("%149[^\n]", lista[i].endereco);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("Digite seu pedido: \n");
                scanf("%299[^\n]", lista[i].pedido);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("Digite o valor total: \n");
                scanf("%9[^\n]", lista[i].valor);
                fflush(stdin);

                system("cls");

                printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo);
                printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                system("pause");

                i = i + 1;
                codigo = codigo + 1;
                break;

            case 2:
                system("cls");

                printf("Insira o codigo que deseja buscar:\n");
                scanf("%d", &busca);
                fflush(stdin);

                i = 0;
                acha = 0;

                while(i < TAM && acha == 0)
                {
                    if(codigo == busca)
                    {
                        acha = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        codigo = codigo + 1;
                    }

                    if(acha == 1)
                    {
                        printf("=============================\n");
                        printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo);
                        printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                        printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                        printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                        printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                        printf("=============================\n");
                        system("pause");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("\n Codigo nao encontrado\n");
                        system("pause");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 3:
                system("cls");

                c = 0;

                for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    printf("Codigo: %d\n", c);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                    printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                    printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                    printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                    printf("=============================\n");

                    c = c + 1;
                }
                system("pause");
                break;

            case 4:
                return 0;

            default:
                printf("Opcao invalido\n");
                system("pause");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add more compiler options to show warnings. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/9nYbTMKoo) - Fix _all_ warnings.

Comment: Also, the sizes of all your string `scanf`s is `1` to large. If you have `char nome[50];` you should `scanf` for max `49` characters - and `%[...]` should _not_ be followed by `s`. Also, **test** that your `scanf`s succeed by checking the return value.

Comment: I did what the warnings suggested, and got rid of the "&" of the pointers, but nothing improved. It still only lets me put "nome" and just ends the process, skipping the rest of it. (Forgot to mention I'm new to C programming.)

Comment: Did you fix all the issues I mentioned? Please update your question with the new code.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is UB.  Better to use other ways to consume line remnants.

Comment: You also still don't check if `scanf` succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the immediate cause is this

```
int busca, acha, i, menu; <<<<=== declare i , but not set to a value
....
scanf("%49[^\n]", lista[i].nome); <<<==== use i
```

you must set i to zero

```
int i = 0;
```