# (C Language) New order overwrites previous ones

Tags: c

Yet another issue came up. Everything works just fine, but all that's left is to figure out how to put each input up in separate arrays, so the searching function I created would work properly. Whenever I put a couple of orders, then try and search via code (codigo), it only detects the most recent entry. I know the solution has something to do with malloc() and/or strcpy(), but I don't know the how or where of it.

Translation:
Case 1: Make an order
Case 2: Search your order (via code)
Case 3: List of orders
Case 4: Exit

[If I remove every fflush(), it just lets me put the name, and leaves everything else empty, so I have to keep fflush().]

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TAM 100

typedef struct order
{
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[150];
    char pedido[300];
    char valor[10];
};

int main() 
{
    struct order lista[TAM];
    int busca, acha, i, menu;
    i = 0;
    menu = 0;
    int codigo = 0;
    int c = 0;
    
    while(menu != 4)
    {
        system("cls");
        
        printf("====================\n");
        printf("Selecione uma opcao\n");
        printf("====================\n");
        printf("1 - Cadastrar pedido\n");
        printf("2 - Consultar pedido\n");
        printf("3 - Emitir relatorio\n");
        printf("4 - Sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                
                
                printf("Digite seu nome: \n");
                scanf("%49[^\n]", lista[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf("Digite seu endereco: \n");
                scanf("%149[^\n]", lista[i].endereco);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf("Digite seu pedido: \n");
                scanf("%299[^\n]", lista[i].pedido);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf("Digite o valor total: \n");
                scanf("%9[^\n]", lista[i].valor);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                system("cls");
                
                printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo);
                printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                system("pause");
                
                i = i + 1;
                codigo = codigo + 1;
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                
                printf("Insira o codigo que deseja buscar:\n");
                scanf("%d", &busca);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                i = 0;
                acha = 0;
                
                while(i < TAM && acha == 0)
                {
                    if(codigo == busca)
                    {
                        acha = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        codigo = codigo + 1;
                    }
                    
                    if(acha == 1)
                    {
                        printf("=============================\n");
                        printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo);
                        printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                        printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                        printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                        printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                        printf("=============================\n");
                        system("pause");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("\n Codigo nao encontrado\n");
                        system("pause");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            
                break;
                
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                
                c = 0;
                
                for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    printf("Codigo: %d\n", c);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                    printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                    printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                    printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    
                    c = c + 1;
                }
                system("pause");
                break;
                
            case 4:
                return 0;
                
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalido\n");
                system("pause");
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry for not mentioning what I'm working on. This is sort of a food ordering system, where you put your name, address, what you want to order, and the amount of money you wish to pay. It's a college project so nothing too much is required.

Comment: Your question assumes we know what project you're working on.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` remains undefined behavior.  Other better code exists.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That includes an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of observed output or behavior, and a sample of the desired output.

Comment: "Yet another issue came up. Everything works just fine, " is amiss.  There is much weakness/problems in this code.  Rather than fix one problems at a time (from your [prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73461471/2410359)). consider reviewing all the issues brought up there.  Posting sample input, output seen and expected output helps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to search, the input number is the index of the entry, just check that its not out of range

```
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            
            printf("Insira o codigo que deseja buscar:\n");
            scanf("%d", &busca);
            fflush(stdin);
            

                if(busca < codigo)
                {

                    printf("=============================\n");
                    printf("Codigo: %d\n", busca );
                    printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[busca ].nome);
                    printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[busca ].endereco);
                    printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[busca ].pedido);
                    printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[busca].valor);
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    system("pause");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n Codigo nao encontrado\n");
                    system("pause");
                    break;
                }
            
        
            break;
```